# Merging two RTFs in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, rtf

I have two strings (RTFs), that I'd have to merge somehow - *insert a new line between the two* -, to display in a RichEditBox, in UWP. I have read a workaround where merging the two is done by the usage of two RichTextBox controls, but in UWP, that's not really an option (and I can't display the two RTFs in two RichEditBox controls either). Is there an alternative way, without using 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using [RichEditBox class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox), we can merge two RTFs by taking advantage of
[**ITextDocument** interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.aspx) and [**ITextRange** interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextrange.aspx). Following is a simple sample:

```
var rtf1 = @"{\rtf1{\fonttbl{\f0 Verdana;}{\f1 Arial;}{\f2 Verdana;}{\f3 Calibri;}}{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;}\f0\cf2 This is red text marked by Verdana font.\par}";

// Sets rtf1 as the content of the document
editor.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, rtf1);

// Get a new text range for the active story of the document.
var range = editor.Document.GetRange(0, rtf1.Length);

// Collapses the text range into a degenerate point at the end of the range for inserting.
range.Collapse(false);

var rtf2 = @"{\rtf1{\fonttbl{\f0 Times New Roman;}}{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue255;}\f0\cf2 This is blue text marked by Times New Roman font.\par}";

// Inserts rtf2
range.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, rtf2);

//var newrtf = string.Empty;
//editor.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out newrtf);

//System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newrtf);
```

This will merges rtf2 to the end of rtf1 and it will automatically creates a new valid RTF. You can retrieve the new RTF with [ITextDocument.GetText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.gettext.aspx).